# Error NoSuchAlgorithmException con jarsigner en parrot

Tags: android

Necesito firmar un apk, ya genere el keystore con apktool y ahora quería utilizar "jarsigner" para firmar la apk y me arroja un error, que no logro saber que es, si me pueden ayudar.[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: No tienes disponible el algoritmo de cifrado que elegiste. Ahí te lo está diciendo. Seguro que es `...whitRSA`? No será `SHA1withRSA`?

Comment: Tienes toda la razón, se me equivoque al escribir, gracias

Answer (score 0, accepted):

El error `NoSuchAlgorithmException` indica que no existe el algoritmo, en este caso, esta mal escrito y debe ser : "-sigalg SHA1withRSA",

```
jarsigner -verbose -sigalg SHA1withRSA -digestalg SHA1 -keystore naruto.keystore naruto-modificada.apk naruto
```

Pero no es necesario definir el algoritmo por lo que puedes realizar la firna de esta forma:

```
jarsigner -keystore naruto.keystore -storepass <password> naruto-modificada.apk naruto
```

Comment: Gracias por el dato corregí SHA1whitRSA por SHA1withRSA  y  probe con     jarsigner -keystore naruto.keystore -storepass <password> naruto-modificada.apk naruto    y anduvo perfecto,  gracias.